# How to draw edittext like what's app android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

[image]

How to create edit text like whatsapp with this border

Comment: Simply use a 9 patch

Comment: other wise use back ground image

Comment: Yes. Use a 9 patch for the background.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Edittext with Imageview and in imageview you can set Right triangle image then its look like you want